# issue with printing in haskell and function declaration

Tags: haskell

this is my code:

```
sumDig i = if (i == 0) then 0 else ((mod i 10) + somaDig ((i-(mod i 10)/10)))


main = do
    print (sumDig 4)
```

it's not working and I dont know why... it doesn't compile and the compiler message is not helping

the function is just to sum all characters of a given number, eg: 123 = 1 + 2 + 3 = 6, and it does that using n mod 10 + recursion from n/10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a few errors.

The error about ambiguous types can be fixed by adding a type annotation to `sumDig`

```haskell
sumDig :: Int -> Int
```

Another error is that `somaDig` is undefined. Did you mean to type `sumDig`?

If so, then the last compile error is the use of `/` on integers. You probably want `div` instead:

```haskell
sumDig :: Int -> Int
sumDig i = if (i == 0) then 0 else ((mod i 10) + sumDig (((i-(mod i 10)) `div` 10)))
```